# File structure of libraries folder and detection of module external plugins

Tags: 8, plugins

The module [CKeditor anchor link](https://www.drupal.org/project/anchor_link) require a CKEditor plugin.
Can this plugin be placed in subfolder of the /libraries folder or does it have imperatively to be placed at the root of /libraries ?

More generally, does drupal parse recursively the libraries folder when intenting to detect external plugins ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is documentation for this. Please read the module's [README.md](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/anchor_link/-/blob/8.x-2.x/README.md) file before asking installation questions.

Comment: @No Sssweat Up to u. As far as i am concerned, that change of usage is good to know for those that do not know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libraries folder is no longer managed by Drupal. The project [Libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) doing this jobs in older Drupal versions seems to be deprecated in favor of a composer based concept. Modules still using the libraries folder use their own logic and you have to follow their instructions on the project page or README.